# How can I search for a person who goes by a pseudonym in Wikidata SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

So I have the following wikidata SPARQL that will grab basic biographical information on a person.  If I provide it a pseudonym such as (Madonna, Cher, Beyonce) it will timeout on me every time. Of course if I provide an actual name, such as "Harrison Ford" or "Tom Cruise" it works great.  The problem line is this

```
?person rdfs:label "Madonna"@en.
```

Here is the entire query

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?occupationLabel_en; separator=", ") as ?occupations) ?birthPlaceLabel 
?image (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?spouseLabel_en; separator=", ") as ?spouses) 
?familyLabel ?familyDescription ?qid
WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5. # Select instances of humans
  ?person rdfs:label "Madonna"@en.

  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P569 ?birthdate. } # Retrieve birthdate
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P106 ?occupation. } # Retrieve occupation
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P19 ?birthPlace. } # Retrieve place of birth
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image. } # Retrieve image

  OPTIONAL {
    ?occupation rdfs:label ?occupationLabel_en.
    FILTER(LANG(?occupationLabel_en) = "en")
  }

  OPTIONAL {
    ?person wdt:P26 ?spouse.
    ?spouse rdfs:label ?spouseLabel_en.
    FILTER(LANG(?spouseLabel_en) = "en")
  }

  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P22 ?family. } # Retrieve family info
  BIND(STR(?person) AS ?qid) # Retrieve Wikidata QID

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?birthdate ?birthPlaceLabel ?image ?familyLabel ?familyDescription ?qid
LIMIT 1
```

Here is the [SPARQL Query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fbirthdate%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FoccupationLabel_en%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20as%20%3Foccupations%29%20%3FbirthPlaceLabel%20%0A%3Fimage%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FspouseLabel_en%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%29%20as%20%3Fspouses%29%20%0A%3FfamilyLabel%20%3FfamilyDescription%20%3Fqid%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%20%23%20Select%20instances%20of%20humans%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Bill%20Murray%22%40en.%0A%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fbirthdate.%20%7D%20%23%20Retrieve%20birthdate%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP106%20%3Foccupation.%20%7D%20%23%20Retrieve%20occupation%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP19%20%3FbirthPlace.%20%7D%20%23%20Retrieve%20place%20of%20birth%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage.%20%7D%20%23%20Retrieve%20image%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Foccupation%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FoccupationLabel_en.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3FoccupationLabel_en%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP26%20%3Fspouse.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fspouse%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FspouseLabel_en.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3FspouseLabel_en%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP22%20%3Ffamily.%20%7D%20%23%20Retrieve%20family%20info%0A%20%20BIND%28STR%28%3Fperson%29%20AS%20%3Fqid%29%20%23%20Retrieve%20Wikidata%20QID%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fbirthdate%20%3FbirthPlaceLabel%20%3Fimage%20%3FfamilyLabel%20%3FfamilyDescription%20%3Fqid%0ALIMIT%201%0A%0A) if you want to see it in action.  Of course if I change the SPARQL to search for the QID, it will work, but a user isn't going to know that.

I do know of a solution, and that would be to get the QID of the person from a SPARQL query, and then perform yet another SPARQL query on that QID, but I'm really trying to avoid that. If the solution I propose is the only way to search for a person who goes by a pseudonym, then I guess it is what it is. Let me know that.

Comment: A timeout will also occur when searching for "Travis", but a quick result not found is given when searching for "Travis ".  What are you doing with the " " in the search name?  (I am not knowledgeable with SQPARQL)

Comment: I'm not the greatest with SPARQL also, but the ?person rdfs:label "Madonna"@en. is an exact match for "Madonna" in English.  The reason of course "Madonna " would come back quickly with no results, is there is nobody with the name "Madonna " (with a space).

Comment: `OPTIONAL` for occupation's label should be nested into `OPTIONAL` for occupation itself: https://w.wiki/7rYB

Comment: @StanislavKralin , you helped me again mate.  I'm always forgetting the little things. I didn't even think to try that.  I'll get better at SPARQL soon hopefully.